# Is “Ur-moment” a normal English expression?

Tags: meaning, etymology, contemporary-english, register

The *New York Times* article of this past July 29<sup>th</sup> titled, “The D.O. Is In Now:
Osteopathic Schools Turn Out Nearly a Third of All Med School Grads,” features the growing popularity of the Touro College of Osteopathic Medicine in Harlem, Manhattan among would-be doctors, and introduces the following episode:

> “Gabrielle Rozenberg, in her second year at Touro, remembers the
>   **Ur-moment** that would lead her to this somewhat unconventional path in
>   medicine. Growing up on Long Island, she suffered from chronic ear
>   infections. Her doctor recommended surgery. But before committing to
>   an invasive procedure, her parents took her to a D.O. In several
>   visits, he performed some twists and turns of her neck and head, and
>   within days the infection cleared up.”
>   
>        ― *New York Times*, [“The osteopathic branch of medicine is booming”](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/03/education/edlife/the-osteopathic-branch-of-medicine-is-booming.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&version=HpSumSmallMediaHigh&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&_r=0), 29 July 2014

I surmise “Ur-moment” means a decisive or eureka moment in retrospect. But I don’t find this word in any English dictionaries at hand.

Is “Ur-moment” a normal English expression? Isn’t it “Ah! (or something else)-moment”?

Comment: The expression would probably be understood by most educated native speakers if they applied their understanding of its constituent elements to synthesize a coherent meaning, but it strikes me as being an excessively pompous and elaborate way  to describe what is essentially a pretty banal event: a twist of the neck to remedy an ear infection and a historical turning-point are scarcely comparable in significance. I would also  argue that since it took several visits to the osteopath to produce a noticeable result, it hardly qualifies as a 'moment' of either the ordinary or the urdinary variety

Comment: I consider myself to be a well-educated native speaker, with a much larger than average vocabulary, and I've never come across "ur-" before, to my knowledge.

Comment: @Phil obviously you're not a musician. Urtexts are all over the place, I'm telling you.

Comment: @Reg Actually, I am an amateur musician, but I'd genuinely never come across the term until today. I'm not a scholarly musician though.

Comment: An [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) where "ur-" is standard.

Comment: @Dejan Govc. Thanks. I read your examples. I got an impression that ur-moment is very different sister (or creature) from ur-element though being in the same family. One looks casual, the other looks formal (or accademic).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Arguably, no, *Ur-moment* is not a “normal” English expression for most people.

However, it really depends on the company you keep whether it is normal or not. That’s because
*ur-* is indeed a reasonably productive prefix meaning the original version of something in literary and academic registers, and has been such ever since the second half of the 19<sup>th</sup> century.

It was borrowed from German.  You see it in places like [*urtext edition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtext_edition), just as one example, to indicate the original, unabridged text of some work.  I for example have scads of musical scores on my shelves all labelled *Urtext*. (OED: *“Urtext* or *urtext*: an original text; the earliest version.”)

Regarding *ur-* in general, the OED says that it is a prefix. . . .

> representing German (also MHG., OHG.) *ur-*, denoting ‘primitive, original, earliest,’ as *ur-Hamlet*, *‑origin*, *‑stock*, etc. See also *Urheimat, Urschleim, Ursprache, Urtext.*
>
> G. *ursprache* (= primitive language) has been freq. used in recent English philological works.

One thing that makes *Ur-comment* stand out is its capitalization. That’s for the most part of throw-back to its German origin, where all nouns are capitalized.  The assimilated version in English is no longer customarily capitalized, as you will see from these OED citations:

> - 1864 Max Müller *Lect. Sci. Lang*. (1871) II. 133 ― The most troublesome of all vowels, the neutral vowel, sometimes called *Urvocal*, better *Unvocal*.
> - 1889 Jacobs *Caxton’s Aesop* I. 37 ― Any light he can throw on the Ur-origin of the Fables.
> - 1901 Boas *Kyd’s Wks*. p. xlv, ― The *Ur-Hamlet* may have contained a number of these borrowings.
> - 1926 A. Møller tr. Pedersen’s *Israel* I. i. 245 ― The word *shēm* is found in all Semitic languages and belongs to the absolutely certain ur-semitic components.
> - 1927 A. H. McNeile *Introd. to Study of New Testament* iii. 50 ― It was an *Ur-Evangelium*, a primitive written Gospel, some say in Hebrew, some in Aramaic, on which our Gospels were based.
> - 1937 O. Jespersen *Analytic Syntax* 142 ― Some well-known students of language who even call this [*sc*. ‘S is P’] the ‘urform’ of sentences.
> - 1943 V. Nabokov in *Atlantic Monthly* May 69/2 ― The dreadful vulgarity, the Ur-Hitlerism of those ludicrous but vicious organisations.
> - 1947 Auden *Age of Anxiety* (1948) ii. 46 ― For Long-Ago has been Ever-After since Ur-Papa gave The Primal Yawn that expressed all things.
> - 1949 F. Fergusson *Idea of Theater* i. 26 ― An enactment of the Ur-Myth of the year‐god.
> - 1950 *Psychiatry* XIII. 168/2 ― The concept of ur-language and ur-symbolism is of particular importance in Freud’s thought.
> - 1964 C. S. Lewis *Discarded Image* iv. 54 ― Plato’s ur-Freudian doctrine of the dream as the expression of a submerged wish.
> - 1966 *Punch* 9 Nov. 718/2 ― Above is Leonardo da Vinci’s design for an ur-tank.
> - 1971 *Astrophysics & Space Sci*. X. 363 (*heading*) ― Orientation of galaxies and a magnetic ‘urfield’.
> - 1977 *Listener* 31 Mar. 416/1 ― The importance of the folk example which he [*sc*. Bartók] argued to be one of the ur-sources of music.
> - 1979 *Listener* 14 June 831/1 ― Sir Nikolaus Pevsner’s ur-history, *Pioneers of Modern Design.*
> - 1983 *Sunday Tel*. 13 Mar. 14/6 ― Russell Hoban is an ur-novelist, a maverick voice that is like no other.

Notice how in the fullness of time, it has lost its initial capital. That’s what makes your *Ur-moment* stand out for me: not its existence but its archaic capitalization, which some might consider a trifle “precious” or eye-grabbing.

It does often retain its hyphen, albeit not always.  There is some potential for ambiguity without it.  For example, *urgent* just means demanding, but an *ur-gent* might be Adam.

So you can think of an *ur-thing* (now probably better spelled *urthing*) as the first one, or the archetype, or the defining moment in this case, the seed that gave rise to everything else.

Comment: Re the 1889 citation: isn't "ur-origin" redundant?

Comment: @DavidRicherby *Ultima Thule* is probably redundant as well, but that didn’t stop it from being used.  In any event, the OED just documents the evolving history of usage.  There are plenty more citations where those came from.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It could be a translation of the german word _Ursprung_ (= origin) which also is kind of redundant (_entsprungen_ = originate/arise). I think _Ur-origin_ is probably used to emphasize that it is the very first origin and not a later, independent one.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Arguably, when talking about fables, you could say that the origin of Disney's Sleeping Beauty is the Grimms' Little Briar Rose and Perrault's Sleeping Beauty, because that's what it was based off of, but its Ur-origin is Sun, Moon and Talia, because that is (I think) the oldest known variant of the tale.

Answer (score 10):

***Ur*** in this case refers to *the first*, so Ur-moment means *the first moment*.

This meaning stems from the German [ur-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur-), meaning *proto*, or *original*.

Apart from being bit of a fancy way of saying "the first", it is often used to distinguish from a series of like events, the Ur- being the very first of the series. Alternately it refers to the first during a time where the subject is still in a primal form. For example, [***urlanguage***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urlanguage) is synonymous with [**proto-language**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proto-language#English), an ancestral language whose form greatly differs from its modern decendants. TVTropes also uses the concept of [***Ur Example***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UrExample) to refer to the first instance that a certain trope appeared, which is somewhat different from the [***Trope Maker***](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TropeMakers), where the form of the trope is unambiguous.

Incidentally, there is a bit of a misconception that it comes from the ancient Sumerian city of [Ur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur), well known as one of the most ancient cities in the world. This seems to be a coincidence.

Comment: The German [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur-) page implies that it's a prefix meaning simply "from". For instance, _Ursprung_, "origin" or "source", comes from the older verb _erspringen_, "to spring from".

Comment: Trivia: "Ur language" could also refer to [Ur](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/), a research programming language.

Answer (score 3):

No, the prefix "ur-" is not a common construction in English, as demonstrated by the quoted writer mis-using it and their editor not noticing. As [tchrist's dictionary quotes explain](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187750/63503), the "ur-X" is the original X. The common example is the play *Hamlet*. There seems to have been a play about a character called Hamlet floating around for about a decade before Shakespeare wrote his play. This original play is referred to the "ur-Hamlet". The prefix is also used in linguistics, philosophy and mathematical logic and set-theory.

But the writer quoted in the question talks about an "ur-moment": an original moment. The ur-moment would either be the birth of the universe or perhaps the birth or conception of the person who had the ur-moment. The moment of realising that manipulating her neck could allegedly cure ear infections is not an ur-moment but a *eureka moment* (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: I disagree with your second paragraph: If someone refers to the *urtext* of a play, they obviously don't mean the first text ever written in all of history, but just the first version of that play. Same here: It's the first moment that leads to the further events, not the first moment of all time.
This is also how it'd be used in German :-)

Answer (score -4):

The Old Testament city of Ur was a toponym, a place-name. In the story, the character Abraham, himself an originator of the monotheism practice of his tribe upon which the saga is centered, is said himself to originate from the city of Ur.

So, the common understanding of the the usage of an "Ur-moment" would more than likely be a reference to an "origination of an originating event in one place and at time". The capitalization of the phrase adds even more credence to the theory that the source of the usage is from the Old Testament story meme.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the name of an almost 6000 year old city, named in an isolate  language that was probably dead by 2000BC, only to be mentioned in a book that was not known in Europe until some 2000 year ago, has somehow ended up in German, having changed from Sumerian [_urim_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur) to Proto-Germanic [_*uz-_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=ur), but if you have a source, I'd love to see it!

Comment: The reason it's capitalized is not because of the city of Ur but because the prefix, which is applied to nouns, come from German. In German orthography, all nouns (common and proper) are capitalized.

Comment: @oerkelens You obviously know nothing of proto-Nostratic, the language family that includes proto-Indo-European and Proto-Semitic (and all the African languages plus Dravidian).  There's a one-to-one correspondence between cities in Sumeria and productive prefixes in Old Germanic. For example, Nineveh corresponds to 'un-' or 'in-' (of course with metastasis and vowel change).

Comment: @oerkelens: Is the er- prefix in German a variant of ur- < *uz- used in different contexts (like in erlauben / Urlaub)? And is it somehow related to Russian из?

Comment: @Giorgio - no, I don;t see a link between ur- and -er in German (or their cognates oer- and oor- in Dutch). I don't know about Russian. Erlauben and urlaub are related (as are the Dutch cognates), but I'm not sure that _ur_ in Urlaub is < _*uz_... But for details you'd probably have on our German sister site (if we have that).